# Entity Framework Core - 'There are multiple relationships between X and Y without configured foreign key properties.', but they are configured?

Tags: entity-framework-core, migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have three entities `Card`, `User` and `Category`.

A card can have a category and a user (the owner of the card).

I have used FluentAPI to tell Entity Framework the relations between the entities, however I get this error

> There are multiple relationships between 'Card' and 'User' without configured foreign key properties.

when they are configured.

**User**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxNameLength)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxNameLength)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxNameLength)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Card> OwnedCards { get; set; } = new List<Card>();

    public IEnumerable<Card> CurrentlySellingCards { get; set; } = new List<Card>();

    public IEnumerable<Card> SoldCards { get; set; } = new List<Card>();

    public IEnumerable<Card> BoughtCards { get; set; } = new List<Card>();
}
```

**Card**

```
public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(MaxTitleLength)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public CardTypes CardType { get; set; }

    [Column("OwnerId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

**Category**

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Card> Cards { get; set; } = new List<Card>();
}
```

FluentAPI:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
        builder
            .Entity<Card>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Category)
            .WithMany(c => c.Cards)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.CategoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder
            .Entity<Card>()
            .HasOne(c => c.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.OwnedCards)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

Comment: Error message refers to `CurrentlySellingCards`, `SoldCards` and `BoughtCards` collection properties of `User`. By EF Core terms these are separate relationships, but `Card.UserId` FK can serve **only one** relationship (represented by `OwnedCards` property as specified in your configuration). Looks like you are mixing relational data model with some view/query information. Most probably you should remove these 3 collection properties from entity model.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you! It seems that was the issue!